# _GNU_SOURCE and __USE_GNU

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnu, glibc

I want to use `CPU_SET`, which is a glibc linux-specific macro that should be defined in `sched.h`  The manpage clearly states that `_GNU_SOURCE` must be defined so that the macro is defined.  However, looking at the header, `CPU_SET` is defined only if `__USE_GNU` is defined (there is an `#ifdef` guard).  I seem to remember a few years ago that `_GNU_SOURCE` was needed.

Questions:

1) Clearly the manpage is off.  How do I notify the maintainer that the manpage is incorrect?

2) When did the transition from `_GNU_SOURCE` to `__USE_GNU` happen (either in terms of version or time)

3) Are there circumstances where newer versions of glibc still use `_GNU_SOURCE`?  Or can I safely assume that defining `__USE_GNU` is sufficient?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`_GNU_SOURCE` is the only one you should ever define yourself. `__USE_GNU` is defined internally through a mechanism in `features.h` (which is included by all other glibc headers) when `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined, and possibly under other conditions. Defining or undefining `__USE_GNU` yourself will badly break the glibc headers.

Comment: I still get errors if I use `_GNU_SOURCE` only.  Any other ideas as to why it could happen?

Comment: All feature test macros such as `_GNU_SOURCE` **must** be defined before **any** standard header is included. You can't wait to define it until just before the header you need it for.

Comment: I ended up having to define `_GNU_SOURCE` at the top line of the most inner header file, but it worked :)

Comment: It really should be at the top line of your source file, or even better, on the command line to the compiler in the form `-D_GNU_SOURCE`. Then there's no doubt that it's defined from the beginning.

Comment: On an older SPARC platform, I had to manually `#include <features.h>` to get this to work without expliciting defining `__USE_GNU`.

Answer (score 14):

you have to define_GNU_SOURCE before anything else.  This snippet works here:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>


int main()
{
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_SET(0, &set);
    return 0;
}
```