# #define not propagating to a C header file

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the code from the following link to print the backtrace when a signal is generated:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391?page=0,1
(from article http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/063/6391/6391l3.html)

I made the necessary changes (REG_EIP -> REG_RIP).
I also changed "`#include <ucontext.h>`"  to   "`#include <sys/ucontext.h>`"  to debug my issue which I will explain below.

The top of the file is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

/* get REG_EIP from ucontext.h */
#define __USE_GNU
#include <sys/ucontext.h>

...
```

With the code as is, I get the following error:

```
# gcc ./st2.c -rdynamic  -o st2
./st2.c: In function ‘bt_sighandler’:
./st2.c:22: error: ‘REG_RIP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./st2.c:22: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./st2.c:22: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

However, when I copy the line "#define __USE_GNU" to  the top of "/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h"   (which I know is a very bad idea and is only temporary) as follows:

```
#ifndef _SYS_UCONTEXT_H                                                            
#define _SYS_UCONTEXT_H 1

#define __USE_GNU  
#include <features.h>
#include <signal.h>                                                                
#include <bits/wordsize.h>

............

#endif // _SYS_UCONTEXT_H
```

My program compiles and run correctly.

I am baffled why the #define in my program does not "flow" into the header file "sys/ucontext.h", and adding #define directly into sys/ucontext.h makes a difference.  Any help would be very appreciated.j

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: __USE_GNU is a glibc internal macro that shouldn't be ever defined directly by your application.

Comment: @jwodder  Can you please describe what editing you did to fix the "#include" string in my original post.  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedA: I just put the strings inside backticks (\`) to turn on code formatting and prevent SO from trying to treat the headers as HTML tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  ucontext.h is included from signal.h, and since __USE_GNU is not defined by the inclusion time, REG_RIP does not get defined.  Doing an addition `#include <ucontext.h>` in my C file had no effect.

Adding the line "#define __USE_GNU" right after `#include <stdio.h>` solved the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_GNU
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
```

Adding the #define before stdio.h  does not help, as stdio.h includes features.h which undef __USE_GNU

Thanks to everybody for your help.

Comment: I guess that's one of the reasons why you're not supposed to use __USE_GNU. (See the link in @FogleBird's answer.)

Comment: It's generally best to include such `#define` (as `__USE_GNU`) at the start of the code.  Definitions such as `_XOPEN_SOURCE 800` have to precede the first system header that might be affected by the presence or absence of the definition.  Also, `gcc -H` can be useful; it lists the headers included in the order included with a 'depth of inclusion' indicator too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something else is #including `sys/ucontext.h` before your `#include` gets to it.

The protection in the header file (`#ifndef _SYS_UCONTEXT_H, #define _SYS_UCONTEXT_H`) prevents the header file from being #included multiple times. If this file has already been included before your `#define __USE_GNU`, it will have no effect.

Does it compile if you move your `#define` to the top of your C file?

Comment: Moving the #define to the top of my C file (and remove the a line added to sys/ucontext.h did not have any effect. Same compile error.

Answer (score 0):

`signal.h` is included earlier in your main module (before you define __USE_GNU) Is this the problem?

What if you move the #define to the beginning of your main file?

Also, regarding defining __USE_GNU yourself:

[_GNU_SOURCE and __USE_GNU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296963/gnu-source-and-use-gnu)

Comment: Please see my comment above regarding moving #define to top of file.  Adding both the two #deifne - __USE_GNU and __GNU_SOURCE to my C file did not help.

Comment: @AhmedA Is that a typo here? It's `_GNU_SOURCE` with only one leading underscore. And that must be defined before any glibc header is included, best on the command line (`-D_GNU_SOURCE`).

Comment: That was a typo, sorry about that.  I used _GNU_SOURCE.   Per your suggestion I tried passing it as a compile option, get a different compile error:  # gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE  ./st2.c -rdynamic  -o st2
./st2.c:7:1: warning: "__USE_GNU" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from ./st2.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:303:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition