# C - Implicit declaration of the function "pthread_timedjoin_np"

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, redhat, porting

I am porting a windows library to linux. I need to use timed join to wait for the thread to join in a specific timeout.

When I compile the library on Linux I am getting the warning

> Implicit declaration of the function - pthread_timedjoin_np

I have included pthread.h and have compiled with -lpthread link. I know that pthread_timedjoin_np is a non-standard GNU function. The function first appeared in glibc in version 2.3.3. and somewhere in BCD v6.

I even checked the [Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html) for Linux but got no help. How do I avoid this warning? Any help?

**Edit-1:**
My system is RedHat 5.

Comment: is this c++ or c? If it is c++, use the new C++0x standard std::thread class and it will be portable without you having to worry about it and remove the c tag. If it is C, please remove the c++ tag.

Comment: apologies, it is C! I misused the tag. Let me remove it!

Comment: did you define  #define _GNU_SOURCE

Comment: yes i have defined that!

Comment: Did you `#define _GNU_SOURCE` *before* the `#include <pthread.h>` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes well before including pthread.h !

Comment: Did you compile it using -pthread?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296963/gnu-source-and-use-gnu), is `_GNU_SOURCE` defined before any headers are included? You could also add it to the compiler command, `-D_GNU_SOURCE`

Answer (score 17):

Make sure the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is before any of the your headers are included. Macros are set up by `<features.h>`, which include various parts of the GNU C library. If you've included other headers before you define `_GNU_SOURCE`, `<features.h>` will have already been included and will have not seen `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Even easier, just define it with the compiler adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` as a compiler flag.

Comment: @jparthj Can you show your code (at least where you're including headers) and the command you're using to compile this file?

Comment: @Collin, I have had the same issue and your answer solves it !! Thanks. As you said, `#define _GNU_SOURCE` MUST be before any of headers included.