# clone() function implicit declaration

Tags: c, linux, clone

I am using the function `clone()` to create threads. The problem is that I am having this error during compilation:

```
implicit declaration of function ‘clone’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I included `<linux/sched.h>`. What can be the problem?

Comment: `man clone` - what does it tell you to include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines at the top of you source file

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  
#include <linux/sched.h>        /* or #include <sched.h> */
```

`_GNU_SOURCE` is a **Feature test macro**.

Feature test macros allow the programmer to control the definitions that are exposed by system header files when a program is compiled. In order to be effective, a feature test macro must be defined before including any header files. This can be done either in the compilation command (**`cc -DMACRO=value`**) or by **`#define`**-ing the macro within the source code before **`#include`**-ing any headers.

- [Defining **`_GNU_SOURCE`** internally defines **`_USE_GNU`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297011/319204).
- [**`sched.h`** included **`<bits/sched.h>`**](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/sched.h.html#42)
- [In **`<bits/sched.h>`**, the function **`clone()`** is declared ONLY if **`_USE_GNU`** is defined](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/sched.h.html#78).

Comment: I suppose the **`_GNU_SOURCE`** macro still needs to be defined.

Comment: Yes, unless you're using a `-std` mode that already sets it (the gnuXXX modes do AFAIR)